# pkg-config glib-2.0 error on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, glibc

I've got some C code which won't compile.

The error message when I run "make" is:

```
gcc -Wall -Wno-pointer-sign -g `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 gconf-2.0`
 \      -c main.c Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search
path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glib-2.0.pc' to
the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'glib-2.0' found
```

Doing a quick search on the Mac using locate I can't see any glib-2.0 files so I'm wondering if I have to install it. And, if so, what's the best way of doing so?

Answer (score 29):

Easiest solution: install Homebrew, type `brew install glib`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I went to login page and came back, the order of answers had changed, and I upvoted the wrong one.  Sorry.  I vote for Homebrew.

Comment: This by itself did not work for me. I know this is 5 years old at this point - but this is what came up in Google search. I had to also use the --with-internal-glib flag on the ./configure line.

Comment: Same for me in 2019, using High Sierra.

Answer (score 7):

Using the `--with-internal-glib` flag on the `./configure` command worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'll use a system like [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/). The packages are patched as necessary and dependencies are tracked automatically. It is a lot easier than the DIY way.

Answer (score 3):

**To strictly answer the '2011 question:**

Installation is unlikely to proceed without package dependencies, and the easiest way to install a package is to use a package manager like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) for Mac OS or [ZYpp](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Libzypp), [Pacman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#pacman) or [YUM](http://yum.baseurl.org/) for Linux. [Conda](https://conda.io/docs/) is also worth a look as it is python-based and can manage projects containing code written in other languages such as R.

As your primary goal is to install `gcc`, `brew install gcc` could do the trick and will fetch dependencies such as `glib` and put them where it can find it later.

**Assuming recent readers (novice and advanced) are trying to adapt the OP problem and answers to their own needs, here is more, along with personal contextual information:**

However, as you may have experimented with different installation methods already, different installation paths may exist and available packages may not be where your current manager is normally looking for. 
In my case, `glib-2.0` could not be found either when installing `gtk` as a dependency for `meson _build`. However actually, I had successfully installed [a more recent version of glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) the usual way, but that pkg-config was unable to find.

As I was novice at the time (and still am, like with stackoverflow), and as a `.pc.in` Autoconf template file was giving me a hard time,  I also chose to bypass the issue by entering `brew install gtk` in the hope that Homebrew would fetch the exact version needed of `glib` and install it where most convenient for the package of interest.

**An alternative** that was not mentioned yet was to locate any file starting with `glib` without any version number, install a current version of `glib` the usual way if needed, and add the requested file to the directory, as suggested by the error message. (I wish I had understood and tried Eric and Nathan's solution at the time).

You can add a directory by typing `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/full/directory/path/to/yourfile`, but it would be safe to consult dedicated help pages on the topic.

Comments on how to further improve my answer (form or content) are much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for internet searching this,

In linux

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev